# Ajax - How to wait until php is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a complete noob to Ajax so please forgive me if this is a completely asinine piece of code:

```
for (var i=0; i<11; i++) {
    jQuery('#position').html(i);
    var offset = jQuery('#offset').html();
    var postcall = 'controller.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(scrapurl)+'&scrape_absolute='+absoluteep+'&scrape_season='+season+'&scrape_show='+showslug+'&scrape_defimg='+encodeURIComponent(defaultimg)+'&offset='+offset;
    jQuery.post(postcall,function(data){
    jQuery('#offset').html(data);
    });
  }
```

The goal here is to execute controller.php with the given values and plug 'offset' back into each call using the returned info.   It works but it runs from 0 to 10 instantly and my webserver rejects the subsequent calls.

My goal is to make sure it doesn't call the php again until the last operation has completed.

Comment: You could make the next call inside the callback, but there are several options. I'd recommend building the URL outside of the `post` call, and indenting to help keep things readable, too.

Comment: can you explain better please

Answer (score 2):

The key is to make your next AJAX call *inside* of your callback function.  That way, your next post will not occur until the first finishes.  In your code, because `.post()` is non-blocking (asynchronous), it continues the loop immediately, incrementing `i`/`#position` and firing off the next `.post()`.

To solve this, encapsulate your `.post()` in a wrapper function.  Have a counter that tracks how many times it has been called.  Call the function from the callback of the `.post()`, and you end up with a recursive function that will do the calls in sequence:

```
var position=0;

function doNextAJAXPost() {
    if(position < 11) {
        jQuery('#position').html(position);
        position++;
        var offset = jQuery('#offset').html();

        jQuery.post('controller.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(scrapurl)+'&scrape_absolute='+absoluteep+'&scrape_season='+season+'&scrape_show='+showslug+'&scrape_defimg='+encodeURIComponent(defaultimg)+'&offset='+offset, function(data){
            jQuery('#offset').html(data);
            doNextAJAXPost();
        });
    }
}

doNextAJAXPost();
```

Comment: Ah, I understand in principle, but the example code only loops through once.

Comment: If it only goes through once, that would indicate that the post call itself was not successful on either the first or second iteration (depending on whether or not #offset is updated with the data)

Comment: I tried changing controller.php to simply echo a value, and it got nothing.

Comment: Hmm. Can you access the php directly?  Here is a jsfiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/Kmm4X/  It uses, `.ajax()`, of which `.post()` is just a wrapper, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Hi my php is ending with echo $offset, but the ajax doesn't seem to be receiving it.

Answer (score 0):

use a self executing recursive function

```
(function callself(i) {
  jQuery('#position').html(i);
  var offset = jQuery('#offset').html();
  var postcall = 'controller.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(scrapurl)+'&scrape_absolute='+absoluteep+'&scrape_season='+season+'&scrape_show='+showslug+'&scrape_defimg='+encodeURIComponent(defaultimg)+'&offset='+offset;
  jQuery.post(postcall,function(data){
    jQuery('#offset').html(data);
    i++;
    if ( i < 11 ) callself(i);
  });
})(0)
```